# Shuttle XH61V / i7: 64b windows supported?

Tags: 64-bit, x86, shuttle

I am confused . I have a
- Shuttle XH61V V1.1
- Intel i7-3770
- chipset Intel 6 series/C200

I mistakenly installed 32bit Win7. I would like to install 64bit Win7 but I am confused:
- with this processor & chipset I assumed 64bit is possible,
- the drivers for 64bit are on the site,
- but the device manager says "ACPI x86-based PC" which (i read) means only 32b is supported.
Can I install 64b win7 on this machine?
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PC supports 64-bit operating systems.

What you’re seeing in Device Manager basically reflects the kernel (x86/x64) you have. On a 64-bit installation of Windows, it’ll say “ACPI x64-based PC”.

So assuming you have more then 2 GiB of RAM, you should absolutely go ahead and install a 64-bit version of Windows. If not, it’s not strictly necessary.

Comment: It is important to point out the following: Any processor that supports the **Intel 64 or AMD64** x86 architecture extension **actually is a x86 processor**.   In this case Device Manager is indicating the specific device driver is for a 32-bit operating system.  32-bit operating systems can only use 32-bit drivers while a 64-bit operating system uses a 64-bit driver.  Worth pointing out that 64-bit support is refered to as AMD64 support by Microsoft within packages for the most part.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I am so happy I don't have to run Win7 on 4gb :-)   
Shuttle confirmed as well:  
<i>Yes 64Bit is fully compatible. But still this PC type is listed as x86
hardware.</i>